# Android - Nested DrawerLayout? Or is there an alternative way to implement a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I would like to make a layout for an activity with a navigation drawer that looks like this:

```
Navigation drawer closed:
-------------------------
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                   1   |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|-----------------------|
|        2              |
-------------------------


Navigation drawer open:
-------------------------
|                |      |
|                |      |
|     3          |      |
|                |  1   |
|                |      |
|                |      |
|                |      |
|                |      |
|                |      |
|                |      |
|                |      |
|-----------------------|
|        2              |
-------------------------
```

Section 1 and 3 should be in the same [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) (inside `main_section`).
Section 2 and `main_section` should be at the same hierarchical level in the Activity.

However, the documentation of [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) states that '**DrawerLayout acts as a top-level container for window content** that allows for interactive "drawer" views to be pulled out from the edge of the window.' So I guess what I am planning to implement is impossible using DrawerLayout as I need DrawerLayout to be a parent layout.

How should I go about this so I can implement the above layout structure?

**UPDATE**
Perhaps I might need to add more details of my requirements. Section 2 should not be visually or functionally affected by the state of the navigation drawer. So that means Section 2 should not dim out like section 1 would do when the drawer is open, and touch on Section 2 should not close the drawer. Section 2 should be always active and responsive to user interaction whether the drawer is open or not.

Comment: you mean when navg drawer open, section two should be active and the drawer should not want to close while touching section two?

Comment: @Ramz Section 2 should be always active whether the drawer is open or not. Yes you are correct that the drawer shouldn't close when you touch section 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it.

Here's snippets of my code solution:

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment">

    <!-- add the content of the Section 3 (the navigation drawer) here.
     this entire xml file could be a listview 
     instead of a linear layout, btw. -->

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ccc"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <!-- add the content of the Section 1 here. -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:name=".NavigationDrawerFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <!-- This button below itself is the Section 3. -->
    <Button
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F66"
        android:onClick="test"/>

</LinearLayout>
```